# How to pass promise result into outer function?

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

```
function readData(field) {
    var profileDatabase = firebase.database();
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var name = user.email.substring(0, user.email.indexOf("@"));
    return profileDatabase.ref('/users/' + name + 'id').once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        return snapshot.val()[field];
    });
}
```

I want the readData function to return snapshot.val()[field], but Promise is asynchronous. How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 3):

What you've done is exactly right: Return it from the `then` callback, and return the result of calling `then` from `readData`. The promise `then` creates will resolve itself with that value, and the caller using `readData` will see it in their `then` callback.

```
readData(field).then(function(value) {
    // Here, `value` is the value from `snapshot.val()[field]`
});
```

Here's an example (using `setTimeout` to simulate the database operation):

```js
function fakeDatabaseOperation() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve({
        val: function() {
          return {foo: "bar"};
        }
      });
    }, 500);
  });
}
function readData(field) {
    /*
    var profileDatabase = firebase.database();
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var name = user.email.substring(0, user.email.indexOf("@"));
    */
    return fakeDatabaseOperation().then(function (snapshot) {
      console.log("Got snapshot here");
      return snapshot.val()[field];
  });
}

readData("foo").then(function(val) {
  console.log("Value here: " + val);
});
```