# Axios Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to display data from my API in a React App with Axios.

I've created a simple method that connects to the REST API.

```
import axios from 'axios';
const API_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8888';

export default class ReviewAPI{
    getQuestions(title) {
        const url = `${API_URL}/api/questions/?title=${title}`;
        return axios.get(url).then(response => response.data);
    }
}
```

When I make the API call it returns back the response but as a Promise.

[image]

When I try to map through the response I get `cannot read property map of undefined'

```
export default function Questions({ response, setData, formData}) {
return (
    <Card className="m-3">
        <Card.Header>{response.description}</Card.Header>
        <Card.Body>
            { response.questions.map((question, idx) => {
                switch (question.type) {
                    case "text": return <FormText key={idx} question={question} setData={setData} formData={formData}/>;
                    case "textarea": return <FormTextArea key={idx} question={question} setData={setData} formData={formData}/>;
                    case "radio": return <RadioGroup key={idx} question={question} setData={setData} formData={formData}/>;
                    case "multiselect": return <MultiSelect key={idx} question={question} setData={setData} formData={formData}/>;
                    default: return [];
                }
            })}
        </Card.Body>
    </Card>
);

}
```

Comment: it means response.questions is not an array. How are you passing the response to the questions function?

Comment: Also, if response is a Promise, wouldn't you need to use `.then` to get the inner value? I'm also unsure whether you're returning the value correctly from the original function because I think you need a `return` inside the callback in the return statement (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42831393/how-to-pass-promise-result-into-outer-function#).

Comment: I'm passing the response by calling the method like this `<Questions response={reviewAPI.getQuestions()} setData={setData} formData={formData}/>`

Comment: I did as you suggested, and I'm still getting the same result... `<Questions response={reviewAPI.getQuestions().then(function(value){return value})} setData={setData} formData={formData}/>`

Comment: @ssk, I meant that you should put the return like `return axios.get(url).then(response => return response.data)` combined with what is done in @Ahmed's answer.

Comment: I rewrote my function like this ```async getQuestions(title) { const url = `${API_URL}/api/questions/?title=${title}`; const response = await axios.get(url); return response.data; }``` If I do a console.log before the return it appears to just be the data but then when call the function it's still returning a promise.

Answer (score 1):

rewrite it like so:

```
getQuestions(title) {
            const url = `${API_URL}/api/questions/?title=${title}`;
            let data;
             axios.get(url).then(response => {data = response.data});
           return data
        }
```

when you call the reviewAPI.getQuestions(), all you will get is the data returned;

Answer (score 0):

You need to await the promise before you can map over the items.

In a functional component you need to do this:

```
const questions = () => {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(async () => {
       const res= await reviewAPI.getQuestions();

       setQuestions(res.data);
   }, []);

   return 
      <Questions 
         response={questions} 
         setData={setData} 
         formData={formData}/>
}
```

Comment: I rewrote my function like this ```async getQuestions(title) {
        const url = `${API_URL}/api/questions/?title=${title}`;
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        return response.data;
    }```

If I do a console.log before the return it appears to just be the data but then when call the function it's still returning a promise.

Comment: put an await  when your calling the getQuestions, like this `await getQuestions("title");`

Answer (score 0):

Look for the code in your Axios interceptor

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31632806)